# Date not updating in .alias

Tags: terminal, alias

I have an alias file with the following line:

`alias ss="import /home/User/Pictures/screenshots/screenshot-$( date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S.png' )"`

In terminal, when I type "ss" it runs the command and saves correctly. However, if I run it again, the date does not update. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `date` command is executed at the time you define the alias (not at the time of the first call to the alias. You must quote the `$`:

```
alias ss="import /home/User/Pictures/screenshots/screenshot-\$( date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S.png' )"
```